# Добавление тегов на сайт, возможно при помощи радио баттонов

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, angularjs

[image: Здравствуйте, необходимо на сайте сделать подобную ВК панель, с возможностью добавления]Здравствуйте, необходимо на сайте сделать подобную ВК панель, с возможностью добавления или удаления. Может видел кто-то что-то подобное? Или исходники есть.
Делаю на bootstrap'e

Comment: Вот, нашел еще такую интересную штуку. Может, кому-то полезным будет. http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/

Answer (score 1):

```
   <html>
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-tokenfield/bootstrap-tokenfield.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>   
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield" value="red,green,blue" />
        <script>
        $('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
          autocomplete: {
            source: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white'],
            delay: 100
          },
          showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
        });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```